# How to open mycomputer and control panel on button click?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a application in java swing? In which I need a notedpad. I want to give some extra feature in that notepad, as I want to open mycomputer, control panel, browser etc. directly from the notepad menu? Can you help me someway to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

Also consider the features in [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute external programs in Java with [`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: This is a link to an old version of Java.  Please link to Java 6 or newer.